# Problems with fastreport cgi wrapper

Tags: apache, delphi, cgi, delphi-7, fastreport

I have an application created in php codeigniter framework and a mysql database running on an apache web server (XAMPP installation).

I know fastreport, has two methods of providing reports through the web:

1. Using its HTTP server as a web server to serve the reports
2. Using the CGI wrapper where you can use a different web server (IIS / Apache) to serve the reports with the fastreports application running from the CGI bin

Problem is I wish to use the CGI wrapper method to serve the reports since I already have apache for a web server, but I do not know how to go about it.

Anyone having some experience using the fastreport CGI wrapper?

Answer (score 2):

I have not worked with Fast Report web server myself, but for my own Delphi / Free Pascal HTTP server applications I use Apache as reverse proxy.

CGI would launch the Delphi application for every incoming HTTP request, causing much more server resource load than using the FastReport HTTP server.

It is quite easy to configure Apache as a [reverse proxy](http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies). Then you can launch the Fast report HTTP server (in the same network / on the same server) and all incoming HTTP requests will be routed from Apache to the FastReport server. Security note: use `ProxyRequests off` to make sure that external ProxyRequests are not allowed.

Basic example for reverse proxy (httpd.conf)

```
LoadModule  proxy_http_module    /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyRequests off

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8097/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8097/
```

This is not tested with FastReport, and if the server already needs to server content on the root path (/) the Fast Report web server might need to use a different resource path, for example `http://127.0.0.1:8097/reports/` to allow serving other existing content.

Comment: thanks for the input, helped in pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it working;

Solution:

1. Create a TServiceApplication for starting and stopping the fastreport http server
2. Take care when setting the config.xml, set the port to 8097 *(Default alternative port for the server)*
3. Create the report templates (.fr3) and place them in your reports folder (as per your settings)
4. Create the index.html file (homepage) and place it in the htdocs folder (as per your settings)
5. **First Test - Test that the application works using the http server** i.e. using your browser go to location server:8097/index.html (localhost:8097/index.html) and ensure you can see the homepage

//-----------------------------------------------------

Setting up the CGI

a. Configure apache to use the cgi bin. Copy the following to the httppd.conf file, then restart apache service

```
 ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/" 

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin/">
AllowOverride None
Options ExecCGI
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>

AddHandler cgi-script .cgi .dll .pl .exe
```

b. from the demo provided from the fast reports site, copy the content of the cgi folder to the cgi-bin folder in apache

c. **Second test - Test that you can see your homepage after going to the location**

server/cgi-bin/fastreport.exe (localhost/cgi-bin/fastreport.exe)

Note:

You must make use of the fastreport http server whether you are using the direct option or the CGI option.

Comment: To me the configuration looks like Apache calls a CGI which in turn calls the FastReport HTTP server on port 8097. Quite a detour, because Apache could just "forward" (proxy) requests to 8097, skipping the whole CGI part ... :)

Comment: That is exactly what is happening.